# React + Typescript error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've just started learning React and thought it might be a good idea to learn it alongside TS, but I've been getting this error, and couldn't find a solution on how to solve it.

```
[ts] Property 'todos' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<ToDoList> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & ...'.
```

This is my code:

```
const TODOS: object[] =  [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Todo 1'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Todo 2'
    }
]

const App: React.SFC = (): JSX.Element => {
    return (
        <ToDoList todos={TODOS}/>
    )
}

interface IProps {
    readonly todos: object[]
}

class ToDoList extends React.Component<{},IProps> {
    static props: IProps

    render() {
      return (
        <div>{this.props.todos.map((item: any) => {
            return <h1>item.name</h1>
        })}</div>
    )
}

}

export default App;
```

Is there something I'm missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of your generic parameters to `React.Component` is wrong, the first parameter should be the props. Change to

```
class ToDoList extends React.Component<IProps> { }
```

If you don't use the second parameter you don't have to specify it.

Answer (score 1):

The first generic argument is props and the second one is state.
Change:

```
class ToDoList extends React.Component<{},IProps> {
```

to

```
class ToDoList extends React.Component<IProps,{}> {
```